# Getting info box information from wikipedia

Tags: jquery, json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I found in stackoverflow an answer that retrieves the infobox from wikipedia given a url.

```
var url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + interests[index].name + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
var html = "";

$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
    $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
    result_html += '<p>' + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html() + '</p>';
});
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

The url is valid, although the searchterm has spaces. Example:

**Full Metal Alchemist** would be the **interests[index].name**.

Comment: I think you'll have a big problem here since you are calling a 3rd party site from you script - which is a security violation (search for cross site scripting for more info). What you should do is write a server side script for your site that will take the info you need from wikipedia and call your page (which will be hosted on the same site with the javascript).

Comment: but if i print the $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html(). It returns something and the error i am getting is not that one. although i recognise that it might happen. but i think in this case wikipedia services use jsonP which lets me do it without that problem.

Comment: your code [**works !!**](http://jsfiddle.net/28Np5/)

Comment: Hum thx then it might be the placement of the function. ty very much

Comment: although it works in jsfiddle i am still getting the error i describe on top

Comment: Your error means that `data` doesn't have a property `parse`. Use `console.log(data)` and look at the content in your browsers debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i realised is that some interests of mine dont have wikipedia pages and for that i dont get any response.

Comment: Not quite true. The point is that you're not *searching* the topic, you're hardcoding a page title in your request. You want the [opensearch API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch).